# std::make_map? uniform initialization

Tags: c++, initializer-list, stdmap, uniform-initialization, stdtuple

The following works:

```
std::map<int,int> m{{1,2}};
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,int> tm1{m, 2};
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,int> tm2{{{1,2}}, 2};
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,int> tmm1 = std::make_tuple(m, 2);
```

The following does not:

```
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,int> tmm2 = std::make_tuple({{1,2}}, 2);
```

Is there a way to initialize a map inside a tuple made with make_tuple without using an extra variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just call `make_tuple`, since first arg in this case will be initializer_list.

Specify manually.

```
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,int> tmm2 =
std::make_tuple<std::map<int, int>>({{1,2}}, 2);
```

Create temporary map from init list.

```
std::tuple<std::map<int,int>,int> tmm2 =
std::make_tuple(std::map<int, int>{{1,2}}, 2);
```